# For which $u$ is there a classical solution to $\Delta u = f$ with $f\in H^m(\Omega)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I was asked to determine for which $u$ is there a classical solution to $\Delta u = f$ with $f\in H^m(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ bounded, open with an infinitely smooth boundary?

I think that this follows from the $L^2$ regularity theory of elliptic problems and i answered with $u$ being a weak solution of the problem and $u\in H^{m+2}(\Omega)$.

Is this correct?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Are you sure you were asked for which $u$ and not for which $f$?  For example, you can take any $u \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ and then set $f = \Delta u \in C^\infty_c(\Omega) \subset H^m(\Omega)$.  This is certainly a classical solution.  The question would seem to make more sense going the other way: asking for which $f$ you get a $u$ in a space that is nice enough to give classic double differentiability.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer @Glitch. You have a point but I'm pretty sure that i was asked for which u, but now that you said it, it looks like that there where obvious answers:D. By the way how would you answer that question you asked?